# How to keep millis() at 0?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I'm making an Arduino reverse stopwatch..but Seems to have a problem with millis() function
Whenever I upload the code on Arduino the millis starts running itself..how can I keep it at 0 until I call the millis. or any alternatives to solve it...

```
#include "SevSeg.h"
int button1 = 11;
int button2 = 12;
int button3 = 13;
int value = 10;
int  timer = 0;
bool n = true;

SevSeg Display;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 byte numDigits = 2;
 byte digitPins[] = {9,8};
 byte segmentPins[] = {10,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,1};
 bool resistorsOnSegments = true;
 bool updateWithDelays = true;
 byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE;
 Display.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments);
 Display.setBrightness(100);


}
```

```
void loop() {
   Display.setNumber(value, 1);
   Display.refreshDisplay();
   
 if (digitalRead(11)==HIGH){
   Start(value);
 }  
}


void Start(int value){ 
 while(n){
   unsigned long timerGlobal = millis();
   Display.setNumber(value-timerGlobal/1000, 1);
   Display.refreshDisplay();
   if ((value-timerGlobal/1000) == 0){
     n = false;
   }
   
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Just store the value it returns _when_ you want to start measuring time and subtract that value later. See https://forum.arduino.cc/t/using-millis-for-timing-a-beginners-guide/483573

Comment: There are several threads on writing custom `millis()` functions over on the arduino forums. This one is relatively similar to what you're looking for. It also hints at the issue over overflow which you may want to overwrite if your code will run for a long time. https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-set-a-value-for-millis/49771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
//#include "SevSeg.h"
            int button1 = 11;
            int button2 = 12;
            int button3 = 13;
            int value = 10;
            int  timer = 0;
            bool n = true;

            //Added
            int currentTime = 0;
            long int t0 = 0;
            long int t1 = 0;

            //SevSeg Display;
            void setup() {
             Serial.begin(9600);
             byte numDigits = 2;
             byte digitPins[] = {9,8};
             byte segmentPins[] = {10,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,1};
             bool resistorsOnSegments = true;
             bool updateWithDelays = true;
             //byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE;
             //Display.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments);
             //Display.setBrightness(100);
             


            }
            void loop() {
               //Display.setNumber(value, 1);
              // Display.refreshDisplay();
               
             if (digitalRead(11)==HIGH){
               Start(value);
             }  
            }


            void Start(int value){ 
             t0 = millis();
             while(n){
               t1 = millis();
               if(t1 > (1000+t0)){
                  //has passed 1 second
                  currentTime++;
                  if(value-currentTime == 0){
                n = false;
                  }
                
               }
               unsigned long timerGlobal = t1-t0;
               //Display.setNumber(value-timerGlobal/1000, 1);
               //Display.refreshDisplay();
               
               
             }
             
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In arduino UNO

```
extern volatile unsigned long timer0_millis;
```

```
noInterrupts ();
timer0_millis = 0;
interrupts ();
```

But it makes no sense at all.

Simply remember the previous millis and calculate time passed (by substracting).

Comment: Worked pretty well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a function that subtract the current millis from the previous millis()

The arduino millis() function is not a function that starts a timer. The millis function is meant to get the elapsed milliseconds since the program started.

Keep in mind that the millis() value will overflow afther:
50 days and 70 minutes. so afther this time the millis() will return 0 again and start over again.

You could implement your own timer using interrupts on the arduino. But like a good programmer always say's if something already exits why make it again? just use the millis() and subtract the current from the previous. But keep in mind of the overflow.